# Is it possible to save data as .mat file without using MATLAB software?

Tags: matlab

I have a table of data in Excel and I need to save it as ".mat file". Is it possible to get this file format without using MATLAB? I haven't installed MATLAB in my PC and online MATLAB sites don't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Python you can use scipy's savemat function:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.savemat.html

To get the data from excel into Python, I'd use pandas; something along the lines of

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.io import savemat

data = pd.read_excel('workbook.xlsx')
savemat('my_mat_file.mat', {"data": data.values})
```